How can * both declare pointers and dereference pointers?
I'm confused as to how the dereference operator functions in pointer declarations.
Consider both these scenarios:
int y = 5;
int *x = &y;

int y = 5;
int *x;
x = &y;

The second scenario (separate declaration and initialization) makes sense to me. After reading through many similar questions, I've noted that declaration resembles usage. That is, *x is an integer, so x is a pointer to an integer. Therefore, the assignment of x to a pointer of y makes sense.
What confuses me is the first scenario (combined declaration and initialization). I struggle to understand why int *x = &y; should work. *x is not a pointer, so why should it be initialized with a pointer?
I've had a few attempts at rationalizing this first scenario. Mainly, I'm trying to determine whether declaration in C just has a special grammar where the value that is assigned with int *x = &y; is x, not *x. Nothing else really makes sense to me.
One explanation that I've seen that I'm not very satisfied with is the higher level "treat int* as a type" explanation. I'm not satisfied with it because it fails for int* x, z.

int* (by itself) is not a type. int is a type. Consider int b, *x;. b is an int but x is a pointer to an int. You could do: int y = 5, *x = &y; The * is bound to the right (not the left). When you said: *x is not a pointer, that is not correct. x is a pointer. When you do: int *x = &y;, this is initialization of x. When you do: int *x; x = &y;, this is an assignment (and not an initialization).

The question overlooks the fact that * is also a binary multiplication operator. Why is that not adding to the confusion? Or, putting it another way, why wouldn't that clear up the confusion? Declaration syntax and expression syntax are completely different, as defined by the language grammar.

Given int* x,y,z;, it is an optical illusion. It looks as though we're declaring three int pointers: int *x; int *y; int *z; But, that is incorrect. The better way to write this is: int *x,y,z; and is actually: int *x; int y; int z; (a pointer and two scalars). If we do want three pointers, we would use: int *x,*y,*z;

The meaning of symbols in declarators is different from the meaning of the same symbols in expressions

In declarations, * is simply the syntax used to indicate a pointer is being declared. Otherwise, when associated with a pointer * is the dereference operator that removes one level of indirection. It can be confusing as hell when you start C to see * used in both circumstances. Just separate in your mind that when declaring a pointer (e.g. int *foo = &y;) the * just indicates a pointer is being declared (which is why you are using the address of y as the value foo is initialized with)

This can be made clear in a simple example (as it will reinforce why it is better to bind the * to the variable and not the type). Avoid writing int* a, b, c;. Why? What is being declared? It certainly is NOT 3 pointers to int. Instead it declares one pointer-to int (a) and two integers (b,  c). Writing int *a, b, c; makes that clear....

@CraigEstey "int* (by itself) is not a type"  That's wrong. C17 6.2.5, the formal definition of a pointer type: "A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called 'pointer to T'."

A unary * always represents a dereference.
This may feel familiar and intuitive in an expression: *x means to get the value x points to. In contrast, you may find a declaration less intuitive; what does * mean in int *x?
The way to think of this is that a declaration gives a picture of how something will be used. The declaration int *x says *x will be used as an int. In other words, when we get the thing that x points to, it is an int. The * in a declaration represents the same thing that happens in an expression: dereferencing the pointer.
Kernighan and Ritchie tell us this in The C Programming Language, 1978, page 90:

The declaration of the pointer px is new.
int *px;
is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination *px is an int, that is, if px occurs in the context *px, it is equivalent to a variable of the type int. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear.

As a more involved example, consider int (*p)[];. This tells us that (*p)[] is an int. Since [] is used to access array elements, this means (*p) must be an array of int. And that means p must be a pointer to an array of of int. Just like *, [] does not have a reversed meaning in declarations. It does not mean “is an array of” instead of “access an element of”; it is still an image of how the thing will be used in an expression.
In int *x = &y;, the = character does not mean assignment. It means initialization. And what is being initialized is not the expression on the left side of the =, because there is no actual expression on the left side. In the declaration int *x, *x is not an expression; it is only an image of how x would be used in an expression. In int *x = &y;, int *x is declaring x, so it is x that is being initialized, not *x being assigned.

Got it, thanks for clearing up my confusion on initialization/assignment.

For completeness, you may want to talk about the difference between int y = 5; int *x = &y; *x = 7; and int y = 5; int *x; x = &y; *x = 7; That is, int *x = ... vs. *x = ...
